# swift 4: background fetch is never been called

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, background, fetch

I have setup the background fetch and its working very well from debug->simulate background fetch. However, when it comes to real device is never gets called !!! I have been waiting for almost a week but nothing new !!!

Here is my code and settings
firstly: I have turned on the background fetch capability from capabilities tab and checked its reflecting in the info.plist

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>fetch</string>
</array>
```

Secondly: I have set the UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum to Minimum in the AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    registerForNotifications()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)
return true
}
```

Thirdly: I'm Running the process to be handled when background fetch is called in performFetchWithCompletionHandler

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
            let content =  UserNotifications.UNMutableNotificationContent()

    let documentsPath = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    let destinationSqliteURL = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent("MyDB.db")
    let db = FMDatabase(path: destinationSqliteURL.path)

    if !db.open() {
        print("Unable to open database")
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.failed)
        return
    }
    var title : String!
    if let rs = db.executeQuery("select _Title from Questions ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;", withArgumentsIn: []){
        while (rs.next()){
            title = rs.string(forColumn: "_Title")
        }
    } else {
        print("select failed: \(db.lastErrorMessage())")
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.failed)
    }
    content.title = "Q&A of the Day"
    content.body = title!
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.calendar = Calendar.current

    dateComponents.hour = 8   // 8:00 hours

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(
        dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)

    let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidString,
                                        content: content, trigger: trigger)


    let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    notificationCenter.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
    notificationCenter.add(request) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("ERROR in setting up the scheduled notification request")
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.failed)
        }
        else{
            print("Notification is Sent")
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
        }
     }
 }
```

This perfectly works while debugging it from the simulate the background fetch, however, it is not being called even once while testing it on real device. I came to know that since if it is even called once then I should have a notification is sent every morning at 8:00 which is not the case on real device.

Comment: Maybe This is about Sandbox problem. You may not have permission.

Comment: iOS makes no promises about the timing of the background fetch, however it should've execute at least once in a week. Perhaps there are other factors that make iOS postpone/cancel the background fetch for your app.

Comment: @AliIhsanURAL ,If it is a Sandbox issue then why it works while debugging ... kindly elaborate ... Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Also I said that . Maybe it is about permission problem. In real device some permission is required but in Simulator not.

Comment: @AliIhsanURAL I have checked all permissions on the device I'm testing, I Think all are met (Unless there is another permission needed that I'm not aware of, Which I would request you to clarify it for me). I have even checked if the background App Refresh is turned on from the device settings->My App Name -> Background App Refresh

Comment: What is the code in registerForNotifications()?